# Some strange multinomial averaging

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, functions, stirling-numbers

How do I prove :

$\sum_{j=2}^{n} (-1)^j {\frac {M(n+j,j;2)}{j!}} = (-1)^n n! + 1$?

where $M(n+j,j;2)$ is the multinomial sum $M(n+j,j;2) = \sum_{t_1 + t_2 + \dotsc + t_j = n+j, t_k \geq 2} {n+j \choose t_1 \dotsc t_k}$ which denotes the number of surjective functions from $n+j$ points to $j$ points with at least two elements in each pre-image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$M(n+j,j;2)$ is the number of ways of putting $n+j$ distinct balls into $j$ distinct urns such that each urn contains at least two balls. This is also the number of functions from a domain of $n+j$ objects (the balls) into a range of $j$ objects (the urns) which are doubly-surjective, i.e. every element of the range has at least two pre-images.

This latter problem has been solved in [Notes on Doubly-Surjective Finite Functions](http://capone.mtsu.edu/dwalsh/DOUBSURJ.pdf) by Walsh, who shows that $$M(n+j,j;2) = \displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^j\left[(-1)^k{j \choose k}\sum_{i=0}^k{k \choose i}\frac{(n+j)!}{(n+j-i)!}(j-k)^{n+j-i}\right]$$

Comment: This makes it more complicated triple sum. I have tried using induction and recursion formula by Walsh.

Comment: I would add some comments as to what I have thought more : multiplying by the $\pm 1$ we have to show $n! = {\frac {M(2n,n;2)}{n!}} - {\frac {M(2n-1,n-1;2)}{(n-1)!}} + \dotsc$ where $M(n+1,1;2) := 1$ for the case $j=1$. The terms ${\frac {M(n+j,j;2)}{j!}}$ can be better seen as the set ${\mathcal A}_j$ of all doubly surjective functions $f : \{ 1, 2, \dotsc, n+j \} \rightarrow \{ a_1, \dotsc, a_j \}$ modulo the equivalence that two such are same iff they coincide up to a bijection on the image.

Comment: By changing a image of one point to $x_{j+1}$ and adding to $n+j+1 \mapsto x_{j+1}$ produce some partial order to the disjoint union $\cup_{j=1}^{n} {\mathcal A}_j$. But the Moebius map of this is not the  one capturing the alternate signs in the sum.